# So it seems I can't set a bounty right now, but can't figure out why

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Are bounty offerings throttled?

I want to give away 1,500 rep right now but can't seem to find the "start a bounty" link to set up my third bounty. Do I just have to wait a few more minutes??

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.

"question eligible for bounty in 2 days".

I was looking at newish questions